# Parse JSON data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, cordova

I have a web service which returns this JSON:

```
[{
    "user_id": "1",
    "user_name": "User1",
    "user_age": "20"
}, {
    "user_id": "2",
    "user_name": "User2",
    "user_age": "21"
}, {
    "user_id": "3",
    "user_name": "User3",
    "user_age": "24"
}, {
    "user_id": "4",
    "user_name": "User4",
    "user_age": "34"
}, {
    "user_id": "5",
    "user_name": "User5",
    "user_age": "27"
}]
```

What I want is I want to populate it to some list and also want to get `index of list item` clicked so that I can retrieve more information according to that index value (`user_id`).

What I did is:

```
function fetchFunction() {
    //fn.load('fetchPage.html');
    console.log("fetchFunction is invoked");

    var header = "<ons-list-header>My Inset ListTTT</ons-list-header>";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "fetchJSON.php",
        timeout: 5000,
        //dataType:'text',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
             var data2 = JSON.stringify(data); //to string
             //var data2 = JSON.parse(data); //to string
             console.log("Index of list is: " + data2[0].user_id + " and username is: " + data2.user_name);         

             //alert("Index is: " + data[0]); 
             //$("#myListElement").html(header);
             //$("#myListElement").append(data);

             // Parse 'data' here
            console.log("SuccessED");
        },
        error: function(err) {
            ons.notification.alert("Error: " + err.status + ", " + err.statusText);
            console.log("Error: " + err);
            // console.log(err.status);
            // console.log(err.statusText);
            // $("#div1").text(err.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

`data2[0].user_id` is doing nothing, just returning `undefined`.

I have a `click` function on that `div` called `myListElement` so I want to show the `user_id` on which the click function triggered.

```
if (event.target = "fetchPage2.html") {
        $("#myListElement").click(function(){
            alert("List Item Clicked!");
        });
    }
```

I will love if you give me some idea.

BTW I am using: **Cordova** + **OnSenUI**. :/

Thank You.

**PS:** I have this `ons-list` as a *List*. and want to populate it here.

```
<ons-list modifier="inset" id="myListElement">
    <ons-list-header >My Inset listdc</ons-list-header>
    <ons-list-item modifier="longdivider" tappable>Item A</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="longdivider" tappable>Item B</ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item modifier="longdivider" tappable>Item C</ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

Comment: you want to populate each user in each list-item tag ?

Comment: @warl0ck Aha Yeah. Each user in each list-item, when some user click on that list, so upon the `user_id` I will send request back to server and will open new activity which will be having detail page of that user. But I know many people don't use `OnSenUI` so they may not be able to help me in list-item `ons-list`. That's why I generalise my question.

Comment: You can get help from here: [Unable to call function not getting page.matches OnSenUi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088679/unable-to-call-function-not-getting-page-matches-onsenui/43248549)

Answer (score 2):

If your service returned data with `application/json` then use direct data variable

```
console.log("Index of list is: " + data[0].user_id + " and username is: " + data[0].user_name);
```

**Test Code**

```js
var data = [{
    "user_id": "1",
    "user_name": "User1",
    "user_age": "20"
}, {
    "user_id": "2",
    "user_name": "User2",
    "user_age": "21"
}, {
    "user_id": "3",
    "user_name": "User3",
    "user_age": "24"
}, {
    "user_id": "4",
    "user_name": "User4",
    "user_age": "34"
}, {
    "user_id": "5",
    "user_name": "User5",
    "user_age": "27"
}]

console.log("Index of list is: " + data[0].user_id + " and username is: " + data[0].user_name);
```

If your service returned data with text then use convert data to Json with `JSON.parse()` function

```
var data2 = JSON.parse(data);
console.log("Index of list is: " + data2[0].user_id + " and username is: " + data2[0].user_name);
```

**Test Code**

```js
var data = '[{ "user_id": "1", "user_name": "User1", "user_age": "20" }, { "user_id": "2", "user_name": "User2", "user_age": "21" }, { "user_id": "3", "user_name": "User3", "user_age": "24" }, { "user_id": "4", "user_name": "User4", "user_age": "34" }, {"user_id": "5","user_name": "User5", "user_age": "27" }]'
var data2 = JSON.parse(data);
console.log("Index of list is: " + data2[0].user_id + " and username is: " + data2[0].user_name);
```

Comment: I put `dataType:'application/json',` in my code and it's not accepting it. Can you please add more details, please?

Comment: Ok, you can use fiddler, charles or postman tool for test or watch requests and responses because, which data format returned your service?

Comment: It's **JSON**. I just did it with PHP's `json_encode();` method. *(The same data is returned as in my question)*

Comment: Hmm, so you can use direct `data[0].user_id` without any convert.

Answer (score 1):

With this small change your code works:

```
var data2 = JSON.stringify(data);
data2 = $.parseJSON(data2);
console.log("Index of list is: " + data2[0].user_id + " and username is: " + data2[0].user_name);
```

Output: `Index of list is: 1 and username is: User1`

Demo: http://codepen.io/8odoros/pen/GWLmwB

Comment: Why I was unable to use `data` before and after using `data2 = $.parseJSON(data2);` I can use it. Can you please explain it little bit? and what If I use `dataType: 'text',` ?

Comment: @fWd82, I suppose you mean `data2` not `data`. Before `$.parseJSON(data2)` data2 is just a string. After that it's an object so you can use `data2[0]` to get the properties of the first child.

Comment: So I use: `var data2 = JSON.parse(data);` by replacing: `var data2 = JSON.stringify(data);
data2 = $.parseJSON(data2);` and great it's working. Looks like they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

After using the command `JSON.stringify()` function its no longer a array that you can access, If you are getting JSON object from the server you can directly access as objects like `data[someindex].user_id`.

If you are getting the data as string in that case you can use `data = JSON.parse(data)` 
Here is [JSFIddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cruvu51L/5/) sample

To get the User details on clicking the user:

```js
var data = [{
    "user_id": "1",
    "user_name": "User1",
    "user_age": "20"
}, {
    "user_id": "2",
    "user_name": "User2",
    "user_age": "21"
}, {
    "user_id": "3",
    "user_name": "User3",
    "user_age": "24"
}, {
    "user_id": "4",
    "user_name": "User4",
    "user_age": "34"
}, {
    "user_id": "5",
    "user_name": "User5",
    "user_age": "27"
}]
success(data);
function success(data) {
    console.log("Index of list is: " + data[0].user_id + " and username is: " + data[0].user_name);
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        $("#myListElement").append('<ons-list-item>' + data[i].user_name + '</ons-list-item>');

    }
}

$("#myListElement").on('click', 'ons-list-item', function() {
var index = $(this).index();
 console.log('selected user details: name:  ' + data[index].user_name + '  id: ' + data[index].user_id + '  age : ' + data[index].user_age);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ons-list modifier="inset" id="myListElement">

</ons-list>
```

Here is [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLxvmpvg/3/) link as well.

Comment: Why the first [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cruvu51L/3/) is having `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1` ? Looks like we are parsing it again?

Comment: my bad, here the error is coming because the data is already in JSON format so no point in parsing. this is in case if you get data in string format from server, if you are getting object then just comment it out

Comment: One thing I didn't understand, If my `data` is in `string` as your first  jsFiddle then why would I be needing `JSON.stringify` as it is already in string format. Also to make the use of JSON should I be converting it to `String`, `Object`, or `JSON` itself. Can you please put explaination of these questions to your answer? ** Note: ** I will be deleteing my this comment after you read it.

Comment: In JSfiddle example my data is in object format not string, and as in my answer what I meant is  you should not use JSON.stringify()

Comment: Thank You, I wish I could have power to accept more than one answer. `+1` for `user details` concept.

Comment: Hello, If data is coming from link, it would be `JSON`, if it's declared inside JavaScript file it may be `[Object]` Is this right? Like in your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cruvu51L/5/) How would I know if `data` is `Object` or `String`, I typed `data` in console and it's not recognizing it. `Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: Happy to help, BWT you can upvote/+1 more than one answer but can accept only one by selecting the tick below upvote.

Comment: the JSON data coming is object itself, same as I declared in the example, generally you will be getting JSON data only therefore you wont require to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var myJSON = [{     "user_id": "1",     "user_name": "User1",     "user_age": "20" }, {     "user_id": "2",     "user_name": "User2",     "user_age": "21"              }, {     "user_id": "3",     "user_name": "User3",     "user_age": "24" }, {     "user_id": "4",     "user_name": "User4",     "user_age":              "34" }, {     "user_id": "5",     "user_name": "User5",     "user_age": "27" }];
    function fetchFunction(){
        $('#myListElement tbody').empty();
        $.each(myJSON,function(ind,obj){
            var htmlTemplate = "<tr userID=" + obj.user_id + " onClick='displayUserData(this)'><td></td><td>" + obj.user_id + "</td><td>"+ obj.user_name +"</td><td>"+ obj.user_age +"</td></tr>"
            $('#myListElement').append(htmlTemplate);
        });
    }
    function displayUserData(ref){
        myTr = ref;
        alert("User ID :: "+ $(ref).attr('userID') +" Row is Click");
    }
</script>
<input type="button" onClick="fetchFunction()" value="Fetch Data">
<table id="myListElement" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10">
    <thead>
        <th>My Inset listdc</th>
        <th>Item A</th>
        <th>Item B</th>
        <th>Item C</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank You @Kinjal, You code helps clear confusion and help me alot getting idea. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse json using $.parseJSON() function. Please check example given below:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var data = '[{"user_id": "1","user_name": "User1","user_age": "20"}, {"user_id": "2","user_name": "User2","user_age": "21"}, {"user_id": "3","user_name": "User3","user_age": "24"}, {"user_id": "4","user_name": "User4","user_age": "34"}, {"user_id": "5","user_name": "User5","user_age": "27"}]';  
        var data2 = $.parseJSON(data);
                console.log("Print json data");
                  $.each(data2, function(i, item) {
                        console.log("Index of list is: " + item.user_id + " and username is: " + item.user_name + " and age is: " + item.user_age);      
                  });                        
                console.log("End print");
        });
```